# Is there a way to fire a javascript function on submit without onsubmit()

Tags: javascript, detect, onsubmit

I am looking to write a javascript function that will fire when a user submits a form, however I do not have edit access to the submit button so that I can add the onsubmit function. I am able to add a `<script>` tag, so if I can detect the submit, then I can execute my code.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Made a mistake saying "programmatic access" when I meant "edit" access.  Thanks greyfade.. if that works, then easy peasy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can locate the submit button through the DOM (`getElementByID()` or `document.formname` come to mind) and then set the submit button's `onsubmit` value to a function of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

> however I do not have programmatic
>   access to the submit button so that I
>   can add the onsubmit function

How is that possible?  If you're executing JavaScript on page, you have access to the entire DOM.

Comment: Because I'm dealing with a shopping cart which only allows me to drop content in.   The "submit" button is simply a checkbox in the cart admin interface.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  If the javascript is executing in that page, it has access to the DOM.  Does the submit button have an id that you can use to retrieve it?

Comment: If you can drop in javascript, then you can add your code to the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attachEvent or addEventListener to attach an event for an DOM Object.

e.g. 
element = document.getElementById('submitButtonId');
element.addEventListener('click',doSomething,false);

while "doSomething" is the function name.